# I am trying to organise this code to test over multiple stocks

Tags: python, finance, back-testing

I am trying to formulate a code that tests for optimal MA's on a list of stocks. I have a working code for one stock that simply returns a one line DF with the best result, but I am struggling to try and create a code that runs for multiple socks. I have tried a few ways with writing another function and using for loops, but I keep hitting a brick wall.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

intervals = range(10,50,5)

def period(df,ma):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Return'] = np.log(df.Close.pct_change() + 1)
    df['MA'] = df.Close.rolling(ma).mean()
    df['Position'] = np.where(df.Close > df.MA, 1, 0)
    df['MAret'] = df['Position'].shift(1) * df['Return']
    df = df.drop(columns=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'])
    df = df.dropna()
    
    return df

new = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Return', 'MA','Position','MAret'])
df= yf.download('AAPL', start = '2021-09-01')
for interval in intervals:
        
        df2 = period(df, interval)
        df2['Period'] = interval
        df2['Ret_Cum'] =np.exp(df2['Return'].sum())
        df2['MAret_Cum'] =np.exp(df2['MAret'].sum())
        df2['Edge'] = df2['MAret_Cum'] - df2['Ret_Cum']
        df2 = df2.sort_values('Edge', ascending = False)
        df2 = df2.head(1)
    
        new=new.append(df2)
        new = new.sort_values('Edge', ascending = False)
        new = new.head(1)

new
```

so this block of code gives the right result.
The question now is how do I run this code over multiple stocks?

```
symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
```

I was thinking I needed to do something like

```
for symbol in symbols:
run the above code to produce a DF that has a row for each symbol that contains the result of the backtest
```

I am so hitting a brick wall with this but I am sure it is most likely easy to do......HELP!

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole second half of your code into a function that accepts `symbol` as a parameter?  I don't think it's any harder than that.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply. Yep, I have thought of that, but just struggling to find the right spot to insert the function. I will keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to handle the stocks in a loop process? If you haven't, I can answer that for you.

Comment: Hi, yes, doing the stocks in a loop is fine. The answer is right there, I just can't quite put the pieces together

Comment: Thanks all. Problem solved. It turned out that putting the square peg in the square hole actually was the best way!